# Reset the Setting of HP LaserJet Printer to Default

Tags: printer, hp-laserjet

Is there anyway I can reset the HP laserJet Printer setting to the default? I have a margin issue when printing a Microsoft Word Document and I'm pretty sure it's the setting problem ( Other printers can print nicely without the margin issue).

But I can't seem to find anything on the Internet that shows me how to solve this problem. Any ideas?

My model is laserjet printer 1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find cold reset instructions [here](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&objectID=bpl10822) for LaserJet printers, just make sure to choose the right model as you haven't mentioned it in your question.

---

For the 1010 you can reset your model like so:

> Turn the printer off. Press and hold
>   down the green GO button.
>
> Turn the print on while continuing to
>   hold down the green GO button for at
>   least 5 seconds, but no longer than 15
>   seconds. During this process, the
>   attention LED (!) turns on.
>
> Release the GO button. The printer is
>   ready if the green ready light is
>   steadily on.

[Source](http://forums13.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/bizsupport/questionanswer.do?admit=109447627+1256009434392+28353475&threadId=904491)

Comment: Printer model specified, it seems that there is no instruction for my model, though

Comment: hmm, answer updated with reset instructions for your model.